# function returns value of button javascript

Tags: javascript

I hava 4 buttons with values (numbers) and now I need a function that only returns value of the button.

```js
function myFunction(btn-id) {
  return document.getElementById(btn-id).value;
}
```

```html
<button id="first" class="button" onclick="myFunction()">1</button>
<button id="second" class="button" onclick="myFunction()">2</button>
<button id="third" class="button" onclick="myFunction()">3</button>
<button id="fourth" class="button" onclick="myFunction()">4</button>
```

Comment: So pass the id into the function.  You're not passing anything in.  Better yet, pass the button in so you don't have to look it up, and just get the value.

Comment: The value of **which** button?

Comment: The return value of an `onclick` attribute isn't used, except that if it returns `false` the default action is prevented.

Comment: i need this function for the one other function, where I will check which button is clicked and call this function

Comment: 1) Variable names can't have hyphens. Try `btnId` instead. 2) Pass the `id` to the function, eg `onclick="myFunction(this.id)"` or even better, pass the element itself ie `myFunction(this)` or just the value ie `myFunction(this.value)`

Comment: @Taplar [yes they do](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-value)

Comment: Ah, true.  They do, but *these* do not.

Answer (score 3):

Use `this` in the `onclick` attribute to refer to the button that was clicked.

There's no need to pass the ID, you can just pass the button itself.

You also can't use `-` in variable names, use `_` instead (`btn_id`).

None of your buttons have a value, I've added them.

The return value of an `onclick` function isn't used. In the demo below I've changed it to log the value instead.

```js
function myFunction(btn) {
  console.log(btn.value);
}
```

```html
<button id="first" class="button" onclick="myFunction(this)" value="one">1</button>
<button id="second" class="button" onclick="myFunction(this)" value="two">2</button>
<button id="third" class="button" onclick="myFunction(this)" value="three">3</button>
<button id="fourth" class="button" onclick="myFunction(this)" value="four">4</button>
```

Comment: i do that for math quiz like "who wants to be a millionaire"  and values of the buttons will be constantly changing, but i have to know which button clicked and values that I can compare values with correct answer

Comment: You can use the value of the button to determine which one was clicked. But returning it doesn't do anything. You can assign it to a global variable that's used later, you can call some other function with it, etc.